# Relation between $h:B\to \{0,1\}$ and prime filter $F \subseteq B$

Tags: boolean-algebra, filters

> $\mathcal{B}:=(B,\leq,\lor,\land,^c,0,1)$ is a Boolean algebra. Prove that:
>
> 1. For any prime filter $F$, there is a homomorphism $h:B\to\{0,1\}$ such that $F = \{x\in B:h(x)=1\}$
> 2. For a homomorphism $h:B\to\{0,1\}$, the set $F = \{x\in B:h(x)=1\}$ is a prime filter in $\mathcal{B}$.
>
> *A filter $F$ is a prime filter if it is proper and if $a \lor b \in F$ implies either $a \in F$ or $b \in F$.*

*My work:*
Isn't (i) obvious? I'm unsure how to prove (i) formally. It seems clear that we should be able to define a homomorphism $h$ such that if $f \in F$ then $h(f) = 1$, and $h(f) = 0$ if $f \notin F$. *What am I missing?*

If $h$ is a homomorphism, we know that $h(0) = 0$ so $0 \notin F$, i.e. $F$ is proper. If $a \lor b \in F$, then $h(a\lor b) = h(a)\lor h(b) = 1$. So either $h(a) = 1$ or $h(b) = 1$, hence $a \in F$ or $b \in F$. $F$ is a prime filter! Is this proof complete?

P.S. For reference, $F \subseteq B$ is a filter if:

- $F \neq \phi$
- If $x,y \in F$ then $x\land y\in F$
- If $x\in F$ and $x\leq y$ then $y\in F$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (i), you still have to prove that $h$ thus defined is a homomorphism.

Now, if $h(a \vee b) = 0$, then $a \vee b \notin F$, whence $a,b \notin F$, yielding $h(a),h(b) = 0$ and $h(a) \vee h(b) = 0$.
If $h(a \vee b) = 1$, then $a \vee b \in F$, whence $a \in F$ or $b \in F$, yielding $h(a) = 1$ or $h(b) = 1$, and so $h(a) \vee h(b) = 1$.

So $h(a \vee b) = h(a) \vee h(b)$.
Likewise you can prove that $h(a \wedge b) = h(a) \wedge h(b)$.

It is quite clear that $h(0)=0$ (since $F$ is proper) and $h(1)=1$ (since $F$ is a filter).
Now, a lattice homomorphism between Boolean lattices which sends $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to $1$ is a BA homomorphism (i.e., it also preserves complements); this is very easy to verify.

Comment: Just to clarify, the $0$ and $1$ in $\{0,1\}$ are elements of the Boolean algebra, and not mere numbers, right?

Comment: Your proof for (i) looks great. Is the proof for (ii) okay?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine Yes, they're the minimum and maximum of the BA. Your proof of (ii) looked good to me since the beginning. I forgot to mention it. By the way, the above proof that $h$ is a homomorphism is incomplete. I'll edit it.

Comment: Thank you! I think it would have been sufficient to show that (i) $h(x\land y) = h(x)\land h(y)$ and (ii) $(h(x))^c = h(x^c)$. $h(0) = 0$, $h(1)=1$ and $h(x\lor y) = h(x)\lor h(y)$ follow from these two.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine Yes, there are several equivalent sets of necessary and sufficient conditions. Good luck!